# XCODE : Run Test from Test Navigator in Command Line

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, command-line, xcode9

So, I have a big probleme here. Im working witch Xcode 9 and if I run my Tests inside Xcode, everything works fine! Like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHElC.png)

But if I want to do it inside my Command Line (because we need it for CD) I get some strange Errors, like some of my modules doesn't exist. So this is my command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace myapp.xcworkspace/ -scheme GelbeSeiten -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=11.0' test
```

So what is the difference between the Test inside the Xcode IDE and my command?

Comment: Try pasting the errors you are getting...